# can node.js read php sessions for each user?

Tags: php, node.js, session

Hi,

I have a php based forum that uses mysql to store credentials. As the user logs in with their username and password, php compares the input data with the values in the database and if they match it creates a php session. I want to create a node.js application that allows the user to enter it if they are already logged in on the forum which begs the question, can nod.js read the data from the php session to display the correct user name on the front end of the application?

Right now I came up with this workaround on my javascript client side file:

```
const setUsername = (username) => {
    username = <?php echo $username; ?>;
    socket.emit('add user', username);
  }
```

but since its client side this would allow anyone to change the source code on their side and input the name they want which is a serious security issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can save php session in the database (default location for php sessions is file system) see [session_set_save_handler()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-set-save-handler.php) function for more details.

And then you can easily retrieve this session from the database from `nodejs` side using the appropriate DB driver (if you use MySQL then here is the implementation for [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2))

Comment: but how can node.js know which session belongs to each user

Comment: @CainNuke each session contains a session id, the user sending it with a HTTP request header for example `Cookie: PHPSESSID=enGHumY%2C-2De-F-TDzNHVmEASDAS;` so you can identify the user by this session id (it will be saved in your database as well)

Comment: but there will be hundreds of sessions stored in the database. Node.js will need to know the ID to pull it out. How can node.js know that ID?

Comment: you can pass it as a HTTP header to nodejs app
but you need to put it on a client side first as a custom header like `X-SID: ${PHPSESSION_ID}`

then extract during the request processing: 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.headers)
});

Comment: that sounds more like it. I dont want the user to be able to edit that info.